# busqueda con fetch javascript

Tags: javascript

los datos llegan, lo que no se es como hacer para que el dato que esta llegando colocarlo en el segundo input con id content.

```js
document.querySelector('#campo').addEventListener('input', event => {
  fetch('../cliente_busqueda/productos.php?id_estado='+event.target.value)
    .then(function(res){
      return res.json();
    })
    .then(datos => {
      console.log(datos.data)
      let html = '';
      if(datos.data.length > 0) {
           for (let i = 0; i < datos.data.length; i++) {
               html = `       ${datos.data[i].nombrecli}`;                   
           }
      } else {
        for (let i = 0; i < datos.data.length; i++) {
          html = `       ${datos.data[i].nombrecli}`;
        }
      }
      document.querySelector('#content').innerHTML = html;
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

```html
<input type="text" name="campo" id="campo" class="form-control">              
<input type="text" id="content" class="form-control">
```

Comment: usa la propiedad value en lugar de innerHTML, input no puede contener mas código html dentro como un span o un div, en cambio tiene la propiedad value. Por cierto tu variable 'html' tiene codigo HTML dentro o solo el nombre es?

Comment: Lo que puso @infinit3Loop__ X2 input espera un value, no html, por lo que el metodo .innerHTML falla, en todo caso seria document.querySelector('#content').value = 'html', igual no podras agregar html a un input, solo un string, si quieres mostrar HTML cambia el elemento "input" por un "div"

Comment: gracias, funcionó

Answer (score 1):

hay un problema con tu codigo aunque pareciera estar correcto, Para asignar el dato recibido al segundo input con el id "content", debes asignar el valor a la propiedad value del input en lugar de asignarlo a la propiedad `innerHTML`

deberia ser algo asi:

```
document.querySelector('#campo').addEventListener('input', event => {
    fetch('../cliente_busqueda/productos.php?id_estado=' + event.target.value)
        .then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(datos => {
            console.log(datos.data)
            let html = '';
            
            if (datos.data.length > 0) {
                for (let i = 0; i < datos.data.length; i++) {
                    html = datos.data[i].nombrecli;
                }
            } else {
                for (let i = 0; i < datos.data.length; i++) {
                    html = datos.data[i].nombrecli;
                }
            }
            document.querySelector('#content').value = html; // Asignar el valor al input
        }).catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```